# iOS/Xcode: Select all images from camera roll between user-set dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera-roll

I'm trying to build a simple iOS application where a user sets some dates, and the application then fetches all the images that were taken between those two dates.

I've just started, but currently have the view to select the two dates and successfully log them to the console.

The part I need help with is requesting access to the photos and fetching the photos between the dates.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
- (IBAction)submitDates {
    NSDate *dateFromPicker = [_fromDate date];
    NSDate *endDateFromPicker = [_endDate date];

    NSLog(@"From date: %@ and end date: %@", dateFromPicker, endDateFromPicker);
    //Request images between dates using ALAssetPropertyDate
}
```

Comment: You need to write a custom Image Picker, which uses the asset properties of the images and show only the images in between the specified date

Comment: Ok great, any links to help me in the right directiON?

Comment: You can start from here http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/ and check https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController